# How to replace a parameter value with lowercase in a C# project template using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, templates

I am trying to create a project template for C# and I have an input parameter named "MyClass" as shown in the template configuration below. I want to be able to change the instances of "MyClass" to lowercase if I want after it has been replaced in the template.

This is a sample class template that I want to generate all classes from:

```
//This is myClass <- Change this to lowercase (myClass)
public class MyClass <- Leave this as it is (MyClass)
{
}
```

If I generate a class named "School" from the template, I want the output to be like this:

```
//This is school <- This replacement was changed to all lowercase
public class School <- This replacement was left unchanged
{
}
```

Here's the current configuration of my template:

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "shortName": "test",
  "preferNameDirectory": true,
  "tags": {
    "language": "C#",
    "type": "item"
  },
  "symbols": {
    "MyClass": {
      "type": "parameter",
      "datatype": "text",
      "description": "Renames files containing 'MyClass'",
      "fileRename": "MyClass",
      "replaces": "MyClass",
      "isRequired": true,
      "defaultValue": "MyClass"
    }
  }
}
```

NOTE: The build action of the template file has been set to content and cannot be compiled so I cannot do things like ToLower().

Comment: I don't understand your `Note:The build action of the template file has been set to content and cannot be compiled so I cannot do things like ToLower()`.Do you mean you can't modify this template?

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT It means it means the cs file acting as a template is literally a text file and the contents cannot be compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your `Note:`, do you mean you can't modify this template? So how can you get what you need.

You should modify to add `valueTransform` attribute, this should solve your problem.

["valueTransform": "firtstLowerCase"](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/blob/5c59d4f923d8856b5b0fe590baead24b645d53b6/dotnet-template-samples/content/16-string-value-transform/MyProject.Con/.template.config/template.json)